# Convert int? to bool in conditional

Tags: c#, integer, nullable, conditional-statements

So I created a custom int.tryparse method in c# to try to make things a little easier and cleaner looking. Here is the method:

```
    public static int? BoolIntParse(string number)
    {
        int temp;
        if (int.TryParse(number, out temp))
            return temp;
        else
            return null;
    }
```

Now, I would like to try to use it in this fashion:

```
if(int? someNumber = BoolIntParse(someString))
{
    //do some stuff if its a number
}
else
   //throw some error
```

Which doesn't seem to work. I also tried assigning the value before the condtional such as:

```
int? someNumber = BoolIntParse(someString);
if(someNumber)
{
    //do some stuff if its a number
}
else
   //throw some error
```

And I get the error message `Cannot implicitely convert type int? to bool`

So this isn't legal c#. Is this what a nullible int was designed for (this type of situation) or am I just not doing it correctly? I'm relatively new to c#.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to check if `someNumber.HasValue`.  That should be in your conditional.

`if (someNumber.HasValue)`

or as an alternative, mentioned by @BrokenGlass:

`if (someNumber != null)`

Comment: Thanks. Your answer worked but it looks like my approach really wouldn't save me time

Comment: @StephenGranet Don't over think the problem.  Just use TryParse directly :)

Comment: @jglouie Haha its hard when I'm new ;)

Comment: @StephenGranet You are trying to simplify which is a good thing.  Patterns will jump out at you the longer you use C#

Answer (score 2):

Why don’t you use the conditional logic supplied by the `TryParse` itself?

```
int someNumber;
if (int.TryParse(number, out someNumber))
    //do some stuff if its a number
else
    //throw some error
```

**Edit**: Also, if you don’t need to throw a custom exception, you could rely on the [`Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19.aspx) method to throw the exception for you:

```
int someNumber = int.Parse(number);  //throws error if invalid
//do some stuff if its a number
```

Comment: Yes, the "helper" function doesn't really amount to much help when written this way.

Comment: I hate having to create local variables everytime I want to see if I can parse something. But since it looks like I'm going to have to anyway.... I might as well use the supplied method huh

Comment: Weren’t you already creating an `int?` local variable in your original code?

Comment: I was creating an `int` variable to hold the output of `Int.TryParse` , which I'm going to go back to since my approach above really doesn't clean up my code or save time

Comment: I use your approach when I actually want to keep the null (e.g. to persist it to a nullable column in a database). If you’re just using it for validation, then you don’t really need it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `someNumber.equals(BoolIntParse(someString))` since you are dealing with objects. Below is the code:

```
string someString = "2";
int? someNumber = 2;
if(someNumber.Equals(BoolIntParse(someString))) {
    Console.Write("done");
}
```

That should run.